Jinja2 checkbox values returned as "on" in flask forms
I have a dashboard, where a user can select from a list of available movie genres. They can also select a movie runtime. When looking at the console, it looks like the values are being "posted" to my application. However, the "checkboxes" are being sent where the keys are the individual names, and the value is "on". What I'd like to do is have them post where the values are the names. From there I'd like to use the movie genres, as well as the runtime as a bind parameter for a separate PL/SQL procedure (not shown here/not accomplished yet). However, I cannot find a solution anywhere on here. I think part of the issue is that I am using Jinja templating to dynamically pass in those values to the index.html page.
Anybody on here have any suggestions?
hello.py
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, request, Response
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import requests
import jinja2
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    response = requests.get('https://[my_ORDS_endpoint].adb.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/admin/mymovies/genres')
    # print(response.text)

    genrelist = []

    for i in response.json()["items"]:
        
        genre = i['genre']
        genrelist.append(genre)

    return render_template('index.html', genrelist=genrelist)

@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict('name')
        print(data)
        return redirect("/")

        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)

index.html
 <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0 bd-example-row">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row row-cols-3">
        <div class="col">
          <form action="{{ url_for('handle_data')}}" method="POST">
            {% for genre in genrelist %}
            <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="{{ genre }}" name = "{{ genre }}" autocomplete="off">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" for="{{ genre }}">"{{ genre }}"</label>   
            {% endfor %}

            <label for="customRange3" class="form-label">Example range</label>
            <input type="range" class="form-range" min="1" max="4" step="0.5" id="customRange3" name="customRange3">
            <input type="submit">
          </form> 
        </div>
        <div class="col">Column</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </body>

I have been working on this for about three days straight. I have looked through the Jinja2 docs, Flask. I've watched hours of youtube videos trying to find this exact use case. I've looked into O-Reilly books as well. I haven't been able to find anything that explains or illustrates this issue.

It seems like you want to handle the form data in a way that sends the values of the checkboxes (i.e., the names of the genres) rather than just indicating whether they are checked or not. This can be done by modifying the HTML form and the way you process the data in your Flask route.
Here’s a possible step-by-step solution:

Modify the HTML Form: Change the checkboxes to send their values (i.e., genre names) instead of “on”.
Process the Form Data in Flask: Update the Flask route to handle the checkboxes properly and collect the genre names that were selected.

Step 1: Modify the HTML Form
Change the checkboxes so that their values are the genre names:
<body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0 bd-example-row">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row row-cols-3">
        <div class="col">
          <form action="{{ url_for('handle_data')}}" method="POST">
            {% for genre in genrelist %}
            <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="{{ genre }}" name="genres" value="{{ genre }}" autocomplete="off">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" for="{{ genre }}">"{{ genre }}"</label>   
            {% endfor %}

            <label for="customRange3" class="form-label">Example range</label>
            <input type="range" class="form-range" min="1" max="4" step="0.5" id="customRange3" name="runtime">
            <input type="submit">
          </form> 
        </div>
        <div class="col">Column</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>

In this modification:

All checkboxes share the same name genres.
Each checkbox has a value equal to the genre name.

Step 2: Process the Form Data in Flask
Update the Flask route to handle the checkboxes and collect the genre names that were selected:
@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_genres = request.form.getlist('genres')
        runtime = request.form.get('runtime')
        data = {
            'selected_genres': selected_genres,
            'runtime': runtime
        }
        print(data)
        # You can now use `selected_genres` and `runtime` for your PL/SQL procedure
        return redirect("/")

In this modification:

request.form.getlist('genres') collects all the values (genre names) of the checked checkboxes.
request.form.get('runtime') collects the runtime value.

With these changes:

The form now correctly sends the values of the selected checkboxes (the genre names).
The Flask route processes these values and you can now use them for further processing, such as binding them to a PL/SQL procedure.

